I tried to install ghidra but i struggle with defining the path to jdk/jre
I wanted to make ghidra run on my linux Ubuntu machine. When i try to start ghidra asks for the path to the jdk (on my machine there is version 17 running). Everytime i give a path i get any error. The last, and i think the nearest on the solution, was the following error-code: 'Java version 17.0.12 (64-bit) is outside of supported range: [21+ 64-bit]'. I dont know how to interpret this error and i have no idea how i make ghidra run.
I searched the whole internet for a solution. In every treat they have written that updating jdk/jre helped. I tried too but without any success. There wasnt any other solution for my problem.

I downloaded Ghidra the other day and struggling with this as well, then realized my mistake.
First, and forgive me if you know this already, there's a difference between the Java Developer Kit (JDK) and the Java Runtime Environment (JRE). Most distros will come with some JRE version installed. On linux, it's typically installed by following the links from
which java

and then following the symbolic links. This is the JRE which just supports running java applications that are already in bytecode, IRRC.
So, what Ghidra needs is the JDK.Developers would also download a JDK to get all the libraries and compilers to turn src into bytecode for the JRE.
To do this, you need to download a supported version of the JDK. From the Ghidra Installation Guide.../InstallationGuide.html#Requirements, you can follow links to supported JDKs.
I decided to use the https://adoptium.net/temurin/releases/.
Second, and this was my stupid mistake, make sure to select the right version of JDK for the specific OS and processor architecture. (duh duh duh) I just clicked on the first thing like a coked-out monkey and got the wrong version.
Third, when you download and follow the instructions to untar in the Install Guide, make sure that you have the right permissions for the folder that has the JDK you just installed. Ghidra appears to be looking for 777 perms or rwxrwxrwx for the directories.
I created /usr/java, sudo chmod 777 and then downloaded the tar to the java directory. From there, you can untar.
In my case, the path I ended up providing to Ghidra was: /usr/java/jdk-21.0.5+11
HTH!
